# Can I override some attribute of drawable shape?

Tags: android, android-drawable, shapedrawable

I have two buttons, they are same shape, only color is different

b1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#000000" />
    <solid
        android:color="#ff0000"/>
</shape>
```

b2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#000000" />
    <solid
        android:color="#00ff00"/>
</shape>
```

layout.xml

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/b1"
    android:text="B1" />


<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/b2"
    android:text="B2" />
```

If I want to create 100 button with different colors, I need create 100 drawable xml.

Can I only create one drawable xml, and then override color or other attributes in layout xml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Via XML no you can't. XML are fixed elements if you need dynamic processing, use Java.

In your specific case you can try to achieve what you need using the Drawable paint and ColorFilter, something like that:

```
Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
ShapeDrawable sd = (ShapeDrawable) b1.getBackground();
sb.getPaint().setColor(color);
sb.setColorFilter(... something);
```

Comment: Tnx. I needed this solution for MaterialTextView and had to change ShapeDrawable to GradientDrawable. In my case to change background color of textview apply this code (in kotlin):  (binding.myTextView.background as GradientDrawable).color = ColorStateList.valueOf(getColorAttr(binding.root.context, R.attr.colorPrimary))