# Button corner radius for custom button colors

Tags: android, xamarin, styles, drawable

I have 5 buttons and they are all in different colors, the color is indicated in the style of this button. But I need to change the rounding of the corners of the buttons, but that the colors of the buttons remain the same. When i create a new drawable and assign it to buttons, then all my byttons have a white color.

The drawable color overwrite colorButtonNormal, also i don't want to create a five drawable files.

```
<!---PRIMARY BUTTON-->
    <style
        name="PrimaryButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:fontWeight">600</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/primary_button</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BlackButton" parent="PrimaryButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/black</item>
    </style>

    <style name="GrayButton" parent="PrimaryButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/gray</item>
    </style>
//...

primary_button.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape>
      <corners android:radius="5dip"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

I found the same theme 
[Can I override some attribute of drawable shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31286941/can-i-override-some-attribute-of-drawable-shape)
but can i define corner radius from other resource or etc?

Answer (score 0):

> I found the same theme Can I override some attribute of drawable shape? but can i define corner radius from other resource or etc?

The answer is no. There is no other way to define corner radius from other resource or etc, unless you want to create a custom `View` that functions totally like a button and be drawn with rounded corner.

The easiest way to override the color of your custom shape is to change it with code, just like what you have found.